# mysql get the order by to happen before the group by

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have three tables and I will just show you the relevant columns here

> Table: groups Columns: group_id, name.
>
> Table: groups_to_message Columns:
>   group_id, message_id
>
> Table: messages Columns: message_id,
>   created (date)

I need to basically find the last message for each group, with out showing duplicate groups.

I've tried using group by like this:

```
SELECT m.created, g.group_id 
FROM groupss as g 
JOIN group_to_message as gm ON (g.group_id = gm.group_id) 
JOIN messages as m 
GROUP BY g.group_id 
ORDER BY m.created DESC
```

This causes the successful grouping but is done before the ORDER BY so the first result is taken before the sort.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can a message belong to more than one group in your model?

Comment: did you find any solution on this?

Answer (score 3):

If I'm reading your question right, Use MAX().  This should get you the most recent item for each group

Example...

```
SELECT MAX(m.created), g.group_id 
FROM groupss as g 
JOIN group_to_message as gm ON (g.group_id = gm.group_id) 
JOIN messages as m ON (gm.message_id = gm.message_id)
GROUP BY g.group_id 
ORDER BY m.created DESC
```

Comment: That gives the same date for each group, the max date from the table

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  m.created, g.group_id
FROM    groupss g
JOIN    messages m
ON      m.id = 
        (
        SELECT  mi.id
        FROM    group_to_message gm
        JOIN    message mi
        ON      mi.message_id = gm.message_id
        WHERE   gm.group_id = g.group_id
        ORDER BY
                gm.group_id DESC, mi.created DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but it should work:

```
SELECT m.created, g.group_id 
FROM groups as g 
JOIN group_to_message as gm ON (g.group_id = gm.group_id) 
JOIN messages as m ON (gm.message_id = m.id)
GROUP BY g.group_id HAVING m.created = MAX(m.created)
```